# Huffman Code Tree with Depth 1 less than number of letters

Tags: algorithm, huffman-code

I need to create a Huffman Code tree using n letters and make the tree of depth n-1.

I tried making all the frequencies equal but it did not work for some values of n.

Is there any specific way to solve this

Comment: Making all the frequencies equal does the exact opposite thing, which is to generate the flattest possible Huffman code, as opposed to the deepest Huffman code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of frequencies to do this with the minimum sum is a modification of the Lucas numbers.

The Lucas number sequence starts with 2, 1, and continues with each number being the sum of the previous two numbers (just like the Fibonacci sequence, which instead starts with 1, 1).

```
2 1 3 4 7 11 18 29 47 ...
```

To get the longest Huffman code, replace that initial 2 with 1, 1:

```
1 1 1 3 4 7 11 18 29 47 ...
```

That sequence of *n* frequencies will result in the maximal-length Huffman code of *n-1* bits.

The depth-nine tree is:

[image: deep tree]

Comment: for those not in the know, what would the tree look like?

Comment: @WalterTross Added.

Answer (score 1):

To make the tree depth `n-1` you need to set the probabilities as follows:
for the `ii`th letter, the probability should be `2^ii`, where `ii = 1,2,3,4,...`.
The probability of the last letter should just complete to a sum of 1.

### Example

for the alphabet 0,1,2,3, giving the following probabilities:

```
p_0 = 0.5
p_1 = 0.25
p_2 = 0.125
p_3 = 1 - 0.5 -0.25 -0.125 = 0.125
```

The  three will look as follows:

```
O
|----------|
0(0)       O
           |----------|
           1(10)      O
                      |----------|
                      2(110)     3(111)
```

Adding another letter to the alphabet will change the probabilities to:

```
p_0 = 0.5
p_1 = 0.25
p_2 = 0.125
p_3 = 0.0625
p_4 = 0.0625
```

And the new tree will look like:

```
O
|----------|
0(0)       O
           |----------|
           1(10)      O
                      |----------|
                      2(110)     O
                                 |----------|
                                 3(1110)    4(1111)
```

Comment: That will definitely work. That's the same as the frequencies 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ... Though you can get the same code with a set that grows (or shrinks for probabilites) as a factor of the golden ratio, instead of a factor of two. See my answer.

Comment: Yes I think that the golden ratio is the lowest ratio allowing this structure of the Huffman code tree.